# How do I pass dynamic props to class in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a function called color, that returns a hex color in the form of a string. I would like to set the property color of my class Icon equal to the result of the function color. The result is that the function returns undefined and I can't seem to figure out why.

I have verified that the if statement does work so perhaps I am returning it incorrectly or referencing the function improperly. But why when I set color equal to the result of the function does it not update, and why does the function return undefined?

```
color() {
    if (this.state.value) {
        if (this.state.valid) {
            console.log("*")
            return "#44c0b9"
        } else {
            console.log("#")
            return "#D3D3D3"
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `{this.color()}` I get either * or # which is great, but when I run `console.log(this.color())` I get Undefined when I imagine I should get the returned values. Then when trying to implement `{this.color()}` into my class icon the color is not changed it shows neither colors in the function color, just black.

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', padding:10 }}>
            <Icon
                raised
                reverse
                color={this.color()}
                name='arrow-right'
                type='font-awesome'
                onPress={() => this.color()}
            />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Why are you comparing `toString` and not just `== false` or `!this.state.valid`?

Comment: Are you sure `this.state.value` is true when the `render()` function runs?

Maybe it gets set later, and when you click the icon, you get the right thing in console, but when the icon is rendered, it's not yet ready?

Comment: Check out the update @matejcik

Comment: @Li357 That was a good call and I fixed that for performance, but checkout the update because my issue wasn't related to that exactly.

Comment: I don't see why the code would reach the return statement and return `undefined` instead of the color. Anyhow, why don't you try setting the color to a state value and use it in the `render()` function since you want to update it in `onPress` handler as well?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can declare a local variable iconColor and assign the iconColor value to  color prop of Icon.

```js
render(){
   let iconColor  = this.color() || "#000000";
   return(
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end', padding:10 }}>
          <Icon
            color={iconColor}
          />
      </View>
    )
 }
```

Comment: Your conditional expression caused `this.color` to be called twice. Why not `this.color() || "#000000"`?

Comment: @Li357 Yes, we can Do In that way also. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

About the only way the function can return `undefined` is if you don't hit any of the return statements.

So I'm pretty sure that the first `if (this.state.value)` is not coming through. Your problem is related to that, not to anything else. Try this to see what's going on:

```
color() {
  console.log("calling color, state value is:")
  console.log(this.state.value)
  if (this.state.value) {
    if (this.state.valid) {
      console.log("*")
      return "#44c0b9"
    } else {
      console.log("#")
      return "#D3D3D3"
    }
  } else {
    console.log("%")
    return "#ff0000"
  }
}
```

See [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/B1-Z7hG87) for a working example.